# Не удаляется элемент с блока

Tags: javascript, html, localstorage

Решил создать систему корзины с использованием localStorage, и почти все работает, кроме одного: Если добавить элементы в корзину, а затем удалить, после перезагрузки они все равно отмечаются как «добавленные». Как удалить выбранное в том числе и из localStorage?

```js
let products = document.querySelectorAll('.product-block');
let product_names = document.querySelectorAll('.product-block h5');
let favourite = document.querySelector('.favourite_elements');
let favourite_names = document.querySelectorAll('.favourite_elements h5');
let h5_storage = new Array(products.length);
let h5 = document.createElement("h5");
// Хранилище для ссылок на копируемые элементы H5
let fav_arr = new Array();
let claimed = new Array();
let id;
const compare = localStorage.getItem('claimed');
if (compare != null) {
  for (var k = 0; k < compare.length; k++) {
    if (Number(compare[k]) > 0) {
      id = Number(compare[k]) - 1;
      products[id].style.background = "orange";
      favourite.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", product_names[id].cloneNode(true));
      fav_arr.push(product_names[id].outerHTML);
      claimed.push(compare[k]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(fav_arr);
products.forEach((product) => {
  product.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toggle_favourite(this); // this - ссылка на кликнутый product
  });
});

function toggle_favourite(product) {
  let i = [].indexOf.call(products, product);
  // Номер кликнутого product среди всех остальных продуктов
  if (product.style.background != "orange") {
    h5_storage[i] = product_names[i].cloneNode(true);
    // h5 клонируется, ссылка на клон сохраняется в хранилище под тем же номером.
    product.style.background = "orange";
    fav_arr.push(h5_storage[i].innerHTML);
    localStorage.setItem('h5', JSON.stringify(fav_arr));
    claimed.push(i + 1);
    localStorage.setItem('claimed', claimed);
    favourite.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", h5_storage[i]);
    console.log(fav_arr);
  } else {
    product.style.background = "white";
    for (var j = 0; j < fav_arr.length; j++) {
      if (fav_arr[j] == product_names[i].innerHTML) {
        delete fav_arr[j];
      }
    }
    fav_arr = fav_arr.filter(function(x) {
      return x !== undefined && x !== null;
    });
    claimed = claimed.filter(function(x) {
      return x !== undefined && x !== null && x !== " ";
    });
    for (var s = 0; s < claimed.length; s++) {
      if (claimed[s] == i + 1) {
        delete claimed[s];
        delete fav_arr[i];

      }
    }
    favourite.removeChild(h5_storage[i]);
    localStorage.removeItem('h5');
    localStorage.setItem('h5', fav_arr);
    localStorage.removeItem('claimed');
    localStorage.setItem('claimed', claimed);
    console.log(claimed);
  }
}

for (var y = 0; y < favourite_names.length; y++) {
  if (favourite_names[y].innerHTML == "undefined") {
    favourite_names.parentNode.removeChild(favourite_names)
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Здесь выбор объектов-->
<a href="#" class="product col-2">
  <div class="product-block">
    <img src="img/product.jpg">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A02s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="product col-2">
  <div class="product-block">
    <img src="img/product.jpg">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A02s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="product col-2">
  <div class="product-block">
    <img src="img/product.jpg">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A02s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="product col-2">
  <div class="product-block">
    <img src="img/product.jpg">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A02s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="product col-2">
  <div class="product-block">
    <img src="img/product.jpg">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A02s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="product col-2">
  <div class="product-block">
    <img src="img/product.jpg">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A02s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<!-- Сюда добавляются заголовки-->
<div class="favourite_elements">
</div>
```

Comment: Это точно полный код?

Comment: @2ip да, полный код

Comment: @2ip ахахах
@Саят Умаров сделайте минимальное демо без лишнего кода и вложенности. Код должен отображать ошибку с минимальными скриптами, html. Кода сделайте минимальное демо - найдете ошибку сами в большинстве случаев
На что влияет `var dropDown`? как поможет `class="container"` у дива в поисках проблемы? Упростите код и html до минимального, который можно будет прочитать. Проблема в офрмлении и написании кода скорее там же и ошибка.

Comment: @Greg-- отредактировал, вроде удалил все лишнее

Comment: @Саят Умаров, а что не работает?
[тест на codepen](https://codepen.io/gregOnCodePen/pen/MWbpmaJ?editors=0011)

Comment: @СаятУмаров на [тесте](https://codepen.io/gregOnCodePen/pen/MWbpmaJ?editors=0011) все работает, сократил до МИНИМАЛЬНОГО html, в js менял только `let i = [].indexOf.call(products, product);` так как не понял зачем оно если у нас есть индекс у метода `forEach` В остальном коде даже разбиратся не стал, так как элементы удаляются и добавляются и код не структурированный совсем, читать невозможно.

Comment: @Greg-- проблема при перезагрузке страницы. Выбранные элементы остаются, но не удаляются

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка была тут: `favourite.removeChild(h5_storage[i]);` — при загрузке страницы, массив h5_storage объявляется и остается пустым, а при клике на уже оранжевые блоки (чьи h5 должны были присутствовать в массиве), выдает ошибку, т.к. `h5_storage[i]` — undefined.

---

+ h5_storage хранит DOM-объекты, его нельзя просто сохранить в localStorage через JSON.stringify. Можно было бы вместо них сохранить номера выбранных элементов, но т.к. это продукты, у них наверняка должны быть уникальные id, надежнее будет использовать их (т.к. часть продуктов может завтра пропасть или храниться в другом порядке)

---

```
claimed = claimed.filter(function(x) {
  return x !== undefined && x !== null && x !== " ";
});
//...
delete claimed[i];
```

Элемент из массива удаляется так:

```
let i = claimed.indexOf(элемент);
if (i != -1) claimed.splice(i, 1);
```

---

Местами перепутали, в переменной хранится массив, строка или кто. Нужно помнить, что localStorage.getItem() всегда возвращает строку (или null, если item не существует). Если из контекста кода не очевидно, что хрантся в переменной, можно оставить комментарий где-то рядом (вплоть до полноценного примера всей структуры в комменте, если это сложный объект со вложенностями).

---

В коде требовалось много изменений, пришлось капитально переписать)

Здесь не работает localStorage. Рабочий пример → https://jsfiddle.net/h8sLk46d/1/

```
let fav_root = document.querySelector('.favourite_elements');

let fav_storage = [], init_done = false;

(function fav_storage_init() {  
  let fav_ids = localStorage.getItem("fav_storage");
  if (!fav_ids) return;
  
  fav_ids = JSON.parse(fav_ids);
  // ["ac5f6e", "f36700"] (список id="..." ранее выбранных продуктов)
  
  for (let i = 0; i < fav_ids.length; i++) {
    let product = document.getElementById(fav_ids[i]);
    if (product) fav_add(product);
    // fav_add сам заполняет массив fav_storage
  }
  
  init_done = true;
  // Нужна только чтобы fav_add не обновлял localStorage во время инициализации.
})();

function fav_add(product) {
  let id = product.id;

  fav_storage.unshift(id);
  product.classList.add("fav");

  let h5_node = product.querySelector("h5").cloneNode(true);
  fav_root.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", h5_node);

  if (init_done) localStorage.setItem("fav_storage", JSON.stringify(fav_storage));
}

function fav_remove(product, index) {
  index = index || fav_storage.indexOf(product.id);

  fav_storage.splice(index, 1);
  product.classList.remove("fav");

  fav_root.removeChild(fav_root.children[index]);
  
  localStorage.setItem("fav_storage", JSON.stringify(fav_storage));
}

function fav_toggle(product) {
  let index = fav_storage.indexOf(product.id);
  let is_fav = (index != -1);

  is_fav ? fav_remove(product, index) : fav_add(product);
}

/***/
let products = document.querySelectorAll(".product");

products.forEach(product => {
  product.addEventListener("click", () => fav_toggle(product));
});
```

---

```
p, h5 {
  margin: 4px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}

a.fav {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

---

```
<a href="#" class="product col-2" id="ac5f6e">
  <div class="product-block">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A01s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="product col-2" id="045acf">
  <div class="product-block">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A02s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#" class="product col-2" id="f36700">
  <div class="product-block">
    <h5>Смартфон Samsung Galaxy A03s 32GB White</h5>
    <p>59 990 тг.</p>
  </div>
</a>

<div class="favourite_elements"></div>
```

P.s. Тут напрашивается объект или класс с методами add / remove / toggle. Можете попробовать переписать, когда изучите class-ы в JS.

Comment: Все еще ошибка 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: @СаятУмаров Да, в процессе исправления оказалось легче переписать)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, реально помог)